# PyQT which tree view to display changing data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qtreewidget

Which view to use to display rows of widgets/items displaying progress bar/and other changing items. There will be lots of rows and refresh rate of 0.5 second more or less.

I'd like to be able to change their header order as well as put few rows in groups and so on.

Something similar can be for example download manager where you have lots of data being displayed/updated.

Which view would you guys recommend, QTreeView or QWidgetView or other?

Comment: see this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-network-torrent-example.html

Comment: If you are familiar with the model-view-pattern then go for QTreeView. It is also more suitable for more demanding tasks.

Comment: I have tried using QTreeView and setIndexWidget or something like that to place QProgressbars in QStandardItem() place but I'm not sure if that's good if I have 200 rows with 10 columns each of changing data... I also had issues as the inserted item would not behave as I expected, for example it would not get highlighted when hover over and so on... 

@eyllanesc thanks for that I'm currently going over it trying to see how its build/understand it, thank you!